# No se aplican mis CSS en button y en h4 usando boostrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy diseñando un sitio en laravel con html y css. Usaré el sistema de rutas de laravel para los enlaces, por otra parte le agregué boostrap ya que tiene un carrusel de imágenes hecho en ese framework.

Me está ocurriendo ahora, que en una sección particular no se aplican los css. No puedo hacer hoover en el botón y no puedo personalizar un h4.

Por otra parte tampoco pude darle estilos a los p y al h6, lo solucioné usando `style="color:#;` dentro de las etiquetas.

Mi razonamiento es que boostrap está tapando los css y se sobrepone a estos evitando que se apliquen. He tratado cambiando el ccs de lugar, ubicándolo luego del href de boostrap pero esto no ha funcionado.

También he tratado de ser mas especifico en los estilos como por ejemplo `.nosotros .nosotros-texto h4{` pero esto tampoco me funcionó.

```js
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('titulo','Aleli Accesorios')

@section('contenido')

<!-- Carrusel de imagenes en boostrap!-->

<div id="carouselprincipal" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselprincipal" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselprincipal" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselprincipal" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-bloc w-100" src="../resources/img/1.png" alt="Primer Slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-bloc w-100" src="../resources/img/2.png" alt="Segundo Slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-bloc w-100" src="../resources/img/3.png" alt="Tercer Slide">
        </div>

    </div>

    <a href="#carouselprincipal" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>

<a href="#carouselprincipal" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>

</div>

<!-- Inicio de la seccion Nosotros !-->

<div class="nosotros">

    <div class="nosotros-elementos">

        <div class="nosotros-texto">

            <p style="color:#89908E;">___</p>

            <h6 style="color:#89908E;">NOSOTROS</h6>

            <h4>Bienvenidos a Aleli</h4>
            <br>
            <p style="color:#89908E;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Reiciendis exercitationem ut blanditiis amet voluptatem nesciunt animi 
            architecto eius tempore, ratione magni sequi, neque nostrum inventore.
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn-default">LEER MAS</button>

        </div>

        <div class="nosotros-img"><img src="../resources/img/nosotros1.jpg" alt="" ></div>
        <div class="nosotros-img"><img src="../resources/img/nosotros2.jpg" alt=""></div>

    </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container-principal{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Seccion NOSOTROS */

    .nosotros{
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 80px;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
    }

        .nosotros-elementos{

            width: 1150px;
            height: 400px;   
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .nosotros-texto{
            height: 400px ;
            width: 333px;
            margin-right: 100px;
        }

        .nosotros button :hover{
            background-color: red;
        }

            .nosotros-texto button{
                background-color: white;
                margin-top: 50px;
                border-color: lightgrey;
                width: 180px;
                height: 50px;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: medium;

            }

           .nosotros-texto h4{
            color: red;
            }

            .nosotros-img img{
            height: 400px;
            width: 333px;
            }

.footer{
    background: #000;
}

.margen-interno{
    padding: 0 110px;
}

/* Header, Menu de navegacion y Slider */


.header{

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
            .menuUno{

                display: flex;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
                height: 65px;
                align-items: center;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E2E1;

            }
                .bienvenidos{

                    flex: 1 1 auto;

                }

                            p.bienvenidos{
                            font-family: Verdana;
                            font-style: bold;
                            font-size: small;
                }
                .social{

                    width: 60px;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: space-between;



                }
                    .social i{
                        color: black;


                    }


            .headerLogo{

                display: flex ;
                align-items: center;
                flex-flow: column nowrap;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E2E1;
                height: 180px;

        }

            .logo{

                    width: 205px;
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    height: 160px;

        }

            .menuDos{

                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                height: 80px;
            }

            .nav{

                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                height: 80px;

            }

                .nav a{
                    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    margin: 12px;
                    color: #4f4d4d;

                }

                .nav a:hover{
                    color: black;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>@yield('titulo')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../resources/sakura.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/621bb6ce44.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container-principal">

<header class="header">

            <!-- Cabecera de botones sociales y saludo de bienvenida -->
            <div class="menuUno margen-interno">
                        <div class="bienvenidos"><p class="bienvenidos">BIENVENIDOS!</p></div>
                        <div class="social">
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aleli_accesoriosuy/?hl=es-la"><i class="fab fa-instagram" title="Instagram"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook" title="Facebook"></i></a>
                        </div>           

            </div>

            <!-- Cabecera del logo -->
            <div class="headerLogo">
                        <a href="index.html"><div class="logo"><img src="../resources/img/logo.png"></a></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Cabecera del menu de navegacion -->
            <div class="menuDos">
                        <nav class="nav">
                            <a href="#">INICIO</a>
                            <a href="#">NECESERES</a>
                            <a href="#">CARTERAS</a>
                            <a href="#">BOLSOS</a>
                            <a href="#">VERANO</a>
                            <a href="#">INVIERNO</a>
                            <a href="#">OTROS</a>
                        </nav>
            </div>

</header>

            <!--Seciones/elementos del sitio-->

            <div class="seccion">

            @yield('contenido')

            </div>


<footer class="footer">



</footer>




</div>



<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Habrá manera de que puedas replicar el error en una herramienta como https://jsfiddle.net/ para que sea más rápido ayudarte?

Comment: Hola como estas? Ocurre que tengo 2 archivos php, un Master y un inicio.blade.php que extiende la plantilla del Master. Creo que en jsfiddle no puedo poner 2 archivos php, quiza yo este equivocado y si se pueda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un div mal cerrado lo tienes despues del  correspondiente al logo eso quebra tú maquetación por esa razón puede que los estilos no se aplican como deseas:

```
<div class="headerLogo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <div class="logo"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Debe ser así:

```
<div class="headerLogo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <div class="logo"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Te falta agregarle la clase btn anidada al btn-default(esto claro si quieres que le de los estilos y transiciones que trae booststrap) es decir debe quedar así:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">LEER MAS</button>
```

ahora tienes algunos errores en tu CSS algunos que pude observar son en:

```
p.bienvenidos {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-style: bold; // ESTO NO VA AQUI UTILIZA font-weight: bold;
  font-size: small;
}
```

En el boton tienes separada la pseudo clase :hover

```
.nosotros button: hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

debe estar así:

```
.nosotros button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Tambien declaras antes este :hover y luego su estado normal, deberias declarar primero el estado normal del botón y luego su estado :hover deberia quedar así:

```
.nosotros-texto button {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
}

.nosotros button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Por  último me gustaría decirte que para que mejores tus practicas sería bueno que pasaras los estilos del header hacia arriba y luego los del nosotros es decir que conforme vayas maquetando tu sitio vayas añadiendo los estilos esto te ayudara a localizar más fácilmente las partes de tú página, por último te dejo un snippet basado en tu maquetación con las correcciones, ya solo es cosa de que lo acomodes en tu laravel:

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container-principal {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }


    /* Header, Menu de navegacion y Slider */

    .header {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
    }

    .menuUno {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      height: 65px;
      align-items: center;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e2e1;
    }

    .bienvenidos {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    p.bienvenidos {
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: small;
    }

    .social {
      width: 60px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .social i {
      color: black;
    }

    .headerLogo {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e2e1;
      height: 180px;
    }

    .logo {
      width: 205px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 160px;
    }

    .menuDos {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 80px;
    }

    .nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 80px;
    }

    .nav a {
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 12px;
      color: #4f4d4d;
    }

    .nav a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Seccion NOSOTROS */

    .nosotros {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 80px;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
    }

    .nosotros-elementos {
      width: 1150px;
      height: 400px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .nosotros-texto {
      height: 400px;
      width: 333px;
      margin-right: 100px;
    }

    .nosotros-texto h4 {
      color: red;
    }

    .nosotros-texto button {
      background-color: white;
      margin-top: 50px;
      border-color: lightgrey;
      width: 180px;
      height: 50px;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: medium;
    }

    .nosotros button:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .nosotros-img img {
      height: 400px;
      width: 333px;
    }

    .footer {
      background: #000;
    }

    .margen-interno {
      padding: 0 110px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Titulo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../resources/sakura.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/621bb6ce44.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-principal">

    <header class="header">

      <!-- Cabecera de botones sociales y saludo de bienvenida -->
      <div class="menuUno margen-interno">
        <div class="bienvenidos">
          <p class="bienvenidos">BIENVENIDOS!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="social">
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aleli_accesoriosuy/?hl=es-la"><i class="fab fa-instagram"
              title="Instagram"></i></a>
          <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook" title="Facebook"></i></a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Cabecera del logo -->
      <div class="headerLogo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <div class="logo"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <!-- Cabecera del menu de navegacion -->
      <div class="menuDos">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="#">INICIO</a>
          <a href="#">NECESERES</a>
          <a href="#">CARTERAS</a>
          <a href="#">BOLSOS</a>
          <a href="#">VERANO</a>
          <a href="#">INVIERNO</a>
          <a href="#">OTROS</a>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </header>

    <!--Seciones/elementos del sitio-->

    <div class="seccion">

      <!-- Carrusel de imagenes en boostrap!-->

      <div id="carouselprincipal" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselprincipal" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselprincipal" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselprincipal" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-bloc w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" alt="Primer Slide">
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-bloc w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" alt="Segundo Slide">
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-bloc w-100" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" alt="Tercer Slide">
          </div>

        </div>

        <a href="#carouselprincipal" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a href="#carouselprincipal" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="false"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

      </div>

      <!-- Inicio de la seccion Nosotros !-->

      <div class="nosotros">

        <div class="nosotros-elementos">

          <div class="nosotros-texto">

            <p>___</p>

            <h6>NOSOTROS</h6>

            <h4>Bienvenidos a Aleli</h4>
            <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Reiciendis exercitationem ut blanditiis amet voluptatem nesciunt animi
              architecto eius tempore, ratione magni sequi, neque nostrum inventore.
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn-default">LEER MAS</button>

          </div>

          <div class="nosotros-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt=""></div>
          <div class="nosotros-img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt=""></div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <footer class="footer">



    </footer>




  </div>



  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola ! Te agradezco muchisimo la respuesta, he corregido todos los aspectos que me has mencionado. Lamentablemente el boton sigue sin realizar la accion de hover, de todas formas gracias nuevamente !

Comment: Hola, algo puede que este mal en la maquetación a mi si me esta funcionando lo que edite, normal: https://prnt.sc/qi9tf3 con hover: https://prnt.sc/qi9tni algo que puedes hacer para revisar el maquetado es ver el codigo fuente de tu página seleccionarlo todo y luego ve a [enlace]https://validator.w3.org/[enlace] le das en donde dice Validate by Direct Input pegas tu código y le das en Check, con suerte es algo que este mal cerrado.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Muchas gracias Erick! Al fin di con el problema, estoy usando Laragon para crear un host virtual, este me estaba cargando una version antigua de mi web por lo cual los estilos no se aplicaban. Te agradezco mucho las herramientas que me has dado a conocer y tu tiempo por brindarme una solucion. Saludos y buen comienzo de año!

Comment: Un placer amigo, saludos feliz año!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza !important en las propiedades de tus clases. Ej.

```
.nosotros-texto h4{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Hola Jonathan te agradezco mucho tu comentario, lamentablemente no me ha funcionado, igual gracias nuevamente !